# How can I find out how much RAM my plugins/extensions are using in Firefox 5?

Tags: memory, task-manager, firefox

Is there a Firefox Task Manager (like in Google Chrome) that would allow me to see how much RAM my plugins/extensions/tabs are using?

Answer (score 3):

From Firefox 6+ there is `about:memory`; so you'll need to upgrade to a newer less stable version.

For example, this is what Firefox `9.0a1` displays:

[image]

That's indeed a tab. Extensions are not shown as far as I know; plugins are available as a process:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to do this in Firefox 5.  In Firefox 7, about:memory got a lot of upgrades, including at least part of what you want.

Edit: Another answer has a nice screenshot, but I believe it will show the memory usage for each tab.

Comment: Could you explain more about how the about:memory page might show him this?

Comment: Something like this works in Firefox 5.0

Comment: `about:memory` works in several previous versions, but it isn't as itemized; usually most of the memory is in very big categories that don't help too much.

Comment: Cannot understand what all what is there means. Must pinpoint the culprit...